# Menu bar upon reboot/login scaling at a higher %

Tags: gnome, 20.04, xorg

My Ubuntu 20.04 laptop is attached to a 2K external monitor. Whenever I reboot or logout (this issue began recently), the menu bar is being scaled. To revert back to the normal scaling, I have to set the system scaling to 200%, apply, and then back to 100%, apply. Please see the attached screenshots comparing this.

**After Logging:**
[image]

**200% and back to 100%:**
[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? I do plug the laptop in to a lower resolution monitor while at work. I'm running xorg and on single monitor only mode.

Comment: Currently there is a bug related to the libmutter-6-0 package that is affecting a lot of users. This bug consists in fonts smaller (and sometimes bigger) than normal. I have the same issue in my login screen (my username does not fit the box) and even after login the font size is not ok. See here for the bug status: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440 If you don't want to implement some workarounds, you should only wait for an update of the libmutter-6-0 package.